# Custom cursor not growing in size when hovering child elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've tried looking for a fix everywhere but couldn't find a single clue on why this isn't working. It works over everything that isn't inside another div/container/wrapper.

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1b75432c09.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<body>

    <div>
      <p>Some text i want the cursor to expand on</p>
    </div>

    <div class="cursor"></div>
    <div class="cursor1"></div>

    var cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");
    var cursor1 = document.querySelector(".cursor1");
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
        cursor.style.cssText = cursor1.style.cssText = "left: " + e.clientX + "px; top: " + e.clientY + "px";
    });
</body>
</html>
```

```
    .cursor {
      position: fixed;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      border: 1px solid rgb(255, 208, 106);
      background: none;
      border-radius: 50%;
      pointer-events: none;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transition: 0.1s;
      z-index: 11;
    }

    .cursor1 {
      position: fixed;
      width: 8px;
      height: 8px;
      background-color: rgb(255, 253, 106);
      border-radius: 50%;
      pointer-events: none;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transition: 0.15s ease;
      z-index: 10;
    }

    div p:hover ~ .cursor {
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.25);
      background-color: white;
      opacity: 0.5;
    }

    div p:hover ~ .cursor1 {
      opacity: 0;
    }
```

It only works on parents like div, footer, header, but as soon as I become more explicit, for example **footer p** it just doesn't do anything

Comment: post an example of a non-working implementation

Comment: ```<div>
<p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

If I change the css to **div p:hover ~ .cursor** it won't work, but if I do **div:hover ~ .cursor** it will. It will only work on parent classes for whatever reason.

Comment: It doesn't work, because div p:hover ~ .cursor   is looking for a .cursor element that is a sibling (~) of p:hover.  But .cursor is not a sibling of p:hover.  It is a sibling of div

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what you actually want. Is it that you have just some very specific elements on which you want the cursor to expand, or on all div elements or... If you could show some HTML of the sort of structure you are working with that would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, I want my cursor to expand on some specific elements. I will update the HTML above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

In `A ~ B`, `~` is a *general sibling selector* which selects all the `B` elements that are sibling to `A`. Note both the elements must have the same parent.

**Like in your condition:**
`div p:hover ~ .cursor` here `~` general sibling selector only works when both `p` and `.cursor` elements have same parent `div`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, and how do I select a specific element?

Comment: move `.cursor*` elements under `p` tag element's parent `div` or use `div:hover ~ .cursor`

Comment: That works perfect for one selector, but what if I want my cursor to become bigger on multiple things?